# How to perform checkpoint from PL/SQL

Tags: oracle

I'm performing cleanup operations from PL/SQL which tend to fill up my redo log, causing the database to freeze on the "Cannot allocate new log" condition.

Splitting up the work into smaller chunks didn't solve the problem, because the redo-log files   stay at status=ACTIVE and ARCHIVED=YES for too long. Only after "alter system checkpoint" the dirty logs are written to disk and become available again for the next chunk.

Now, how can I do this from PL/SQL. I tried

```
create procedure cp as begin execute immediate 'alter system checkpoint'; end;
```

but it gave me `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`

I've got the DBA role but that's not effective in PL/SQL procedures. What is the privilege I need to grant?

I know there are parameters to control checkpointing, but I don't want to change these. I only want to manually checkpoint during the cleanup.

Comment: Privileges from roles are not active inside a stored procedure. You need to grant the `alter system` privilege directly.

Comment: try create procedure cp authid current_user as ... (or do as a_horse_with_no_name suggests which is grant directly to user)

Comment: roles are disabled for PL/SQL and any privileges granted via roles do not apply unless you created the procedure with AUTHID CURRENT_USER, in which case role privileges do apply.

Comment: You could also increase the size of online redo log files, or(and) increase the number of redo log files. Increase the frequency of checkpoints by setting [LOG_CHECKPOINT_INTERVAL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams109.htm) parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the procedure is owned by a privileged user, and alter its permissions to run with owner privileges.

That's kind-of like a setuid program in Unix.

The [syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_procedure.htm) is `CREATE PROCEDURE ... AUTHID DEFINER ...`.

The alternative, as commented above by @a_horse_with_no_name and @tbone is to grant `ALTER SYSTEM` privilege to the user running the procedure.

Comment: 'authid current_user' works but I'd still like to know what's the name of the privilege

Comment: AUTHID_DEFINER would be the default, meaning roles are not in effect at all, because checks are done at compile-time and roles are "soft". Only AUTHID CURRENT_USER would do authorization-checks at runtime.

Comment: TIL the required privilege is "alter system". Could you please update your answer to include tbone's comment, thanks.